# how to remove the link in VBA macro that is opening the file it was copied from, not the sheet in the current workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a copied version from  my main excel file (Facilities running) for my coworker to use the copied version is ( Automated Database). When I reassigned the macros buttons to be connected to Automated Database modules and I go and run the macros in my main excel file it redirects me to Automated Database copied Version. I tried that code I found on Stack overflow  and it didn't cut the link. I want the macros to be assigned to the same workbook and not redirecting me to the other workbook.

```````
Sub proper_text()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim name_rng As Range
    Dim name_cell As Range
    Dim name_selection As String
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb.Worksheets("Credentialing_Work_History")
        name_selection = getColRange("Company_Name")
        Set name_rng = Range(name_selection)
        For Each name_cell In name_rng
            name_cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(name_cell.Value)
        Next
    End With
End Sub

````
I also Tried that codes and still didn't work 
`````
Set wb = Workbooks("FACILITIES_DATABASE_RUNNING.xlsm")
    With wb.Worksheets("Credentialing_Work_History")
        name_selection = getColRange("Company_Name")
        Set name_rng = Range(name_selection)
        For Each name_cell In name_rng
            name_cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(name_cell.Value)
        Next
    End With
``````

Set wb = Workbooks("Facilities_Database_Automation.xlsm")
    With wb.Worksheets("Credentialing_Work_History")
        ' First Part
        name_selection = getColRange("Company_Name")
        Set name_rng = Range(name_selection)
        For Each name_cell In name_rng
            name_cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(name_cell.Value)
        Next
    End With

`` Still both of them linked not working.
```````

Comment: Side note: missing a `.` in front of `Range(name_selection)`.

Comment: maybe `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` instead of `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Can you have a dynamic Macro buttons ?. I discovered I was assigning on the same macro button instead of creating new one. Is there a way to make the link dynamic that work for specific workbook instead of creating  a set of new buttons. Did you get my point ?